# If $\psi(x)=\int_U d(x,y)dy$, proof that there is a unique $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $\psi(x)$ is minimal?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

Let $(\Bbb R,d)$ be a metric space and let $\psi:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be defined as $\psi(x)=\int_Ud(x,y)dy$ given a subset $U\subseteq \Bbb R$ that is a bounded member of the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

I'm trying to prove that there is a unique $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $\psi(x)$ is minimum, i.e. for all other $y\in\Bbb R$, we have that $\psi(x)<\psi(y)$, and not just $\psi(x)\leq\psi(y)$.

If $\psi$ were injective then we are done, but it's not always the case. I need to check injectiveness just for the argument that just gives the minimal, but I don't know to do that. Any help on that or any other methods would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the connection between $d$ and the standard metric on ${\mathbb R}$?

Comment: You're trying to prove a false statement. A counterexample is $d$, the discrete metric ($d(x,y) = 1$ for $x \not = y$), and $U = \{0,1\}$.